# Vb.Net - Bytes Written Exceed the Content-Length bytes in XML Post

Tags: xml, vb.net, webrequest, content-length

Ugh, I keep getting a ProtocolViolationException "Bytes to be written to the stream exceed the Content-Length bytes size specified." on the following code.

I've tried setting Content-Length numerous ways with no success.

```
Dim url = "https://domain.com"
Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
req.Method = "POST"
req.ContentType = "application/xml"

Dim utf8 As New UTF8Encoding()
req.ContentLength = utf8.GetByteCount(xml.OuterXml) 

xml.Save(req.GetRequestStream()) // throws the exception
req.GetRequestStream().Close()

Dim httpResp As WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
Dim stReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(httpResp.GetResponseStream())
Dim strResponse As String

strResponse = stReader.ReadToEnd()

Console.WriteLine(strResponse)
```

I've tried setting the content-length using xml.OutXML.Length

Comment: What happens if you omit line: req.ContentLength = utf8.GetByteCount(xml.OuterXml) ?

Comment: The API requires that I send a valid Content-Length header.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048753/how-to-post-xml-document-to-http-with-vb-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx), it makes the code easier and it takes care of properly flushing and disposing all the streams:

```
Dim xml As New XmlDocument
xml.LoadXml("<foo>abc</foo>")
Using client As WebClient = New WebClient
    client.Headers.Item(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType) = "application/xml"
    Dim data As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml.OuterXml)
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.UploadData("https://domain.com", data)))
End Using
```

Comment: I need the Content-Length Header. It is required by the API.

Comment: @Joshua McGinnis, the `Content-Length` request header is automatically set by the `WebClient` based on the length of the data you are sending. So with my example XML, `Content-Length: 14` will be sent in the request. Never try to set this header manually as you might get inconsistent results and violate the HTTP protocol specification.

Comment: I did not know that! How would I print all of the headers so I can this?

Comment: @Joshua McGinnis, you could [enable tracing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590650/see-httpwebrequest-as-string-before-getresponse-without-using-fiddler/3590658#3590658) in your application or install a network analyzer such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).